# iOS Simulator does not slow down CA animations

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

If you use [UIView animate...] you can toggle slow animations in simulator. But if you working with layers and CAAnimation — those animation won't slow down. What is the reason?

Comment: Probably because it only slows down UIKit animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Simulator can only toggle the speed of UIView animations.

As a workaround, simply set the speed property of the UIWindow or an arbitrary root view:

```
view.layer.speed = 0.1f; // 10x slower animations
```

This slows down all CAAnimations within the layer's sub-hierarchy, including UIView animations.